# type object is not iterable Django

Tags: python, html, django

I am creating a personal portfolio website using Django. I am making a new model, called 'Skill', and I want a different instance of the model for each skill which I have. 
I have previous experience with Django, so I am simply doing the same process as always. However, for some reason, this time I get an error when registering the model  - `TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable`. I have already added the skills app to my list of apps.

Does anyone know why this is happening?
Here is my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Skill
# Create your views here.

def skills(request):
    Skills = Skill.objects.all()
    return render(request,'skills\skills.html')
```

Here is my models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Skill():
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 250)

    def __str__(self):
        return (self.title)
```

And here is my admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Skill
# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(Skill)
```

I am not even calling this model yet in any html file - making migrations or running the server will give me this error.

All help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Did you forget to inherit your skill class from models.Model?

Comment: Can you post full error?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have not inherited from models.Model in your Skill model.

Change your models.py as follows

```
class Skill(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
```

I think this answer helped you. :)

Comment: How could I forget... thank you, that fixed it. Can't believe I made such a silly mistake.